# Fetching values preceding a given index value in json field

Tags: python, json, django

I have jsonfield

```
[{"0":"Z","1":"Y","2":"X","3":"W","4":"V"}].
```

I want to fetch all the values preceding `Y` i.e. `X,W,V ...`

```
i = 0
name = None

obj= Model.objects.get(Name=Request['Name'])
for key in obj:
    currentPosition = key[str(i)]
    i = i +1
    if currentPosition == request['Position']:
        continue
    else:
        sendData.append({"Position": currentPosition})
```

When I am adding `Y` in the request it is fetching details for `Z` also.

Comment: `obj` would be an instance of a subclass of `Model` (not an actual `Model`) and would not be iterable as your code seems to assume. You need to access the field within the `Model` object returned by `Model.object.get()`. That JSON field will already be converted to a Python object,  in this case a list with a dictionary as its only element.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values preceding `"Y"` using a simple comparison in a list comprehension:

```
>>> lst = [{"0":"Z","1":"Y","2":"X","3":"W","4":"V"}]
>>> [v for v in lst[0].values() if v < "Y"]
['X', 'W', 'V']
```

To get the values with *keys* preceding the key of `"Y"`, you could use something like this:

```
>>> idx = next(int(k) for k, v in lst[0].items() if v == "Y")
>>> [v for k, v in lst[0].items() if int(k) < idx]
['Z']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are going through each key in the dictionary, and if it's position is the requested position (in this case `'1'` which corresponds to `'Y'`) then it passes over the entry, and in all other cases the position is appended to the output. A minimal change you could make is to have a flag be set to true when the requested position is reached, and replace `else` with an `elif`. An example is given below:

```
i = 0
none = None

obj = Model.objects.get(Name=Request['Name'])
flag = False
for key in obj:
    currentPosition = key[str(i)]
    i = i + 1
    if currentPosition == reques['Position']:
        flag = True
    elif flag:
        sendData.append({"Position" : currentPosition})
```

However there is a few small issue in the above code, as I am assuming `obj` is a dictionary. First there is no order to the keys in the dictionary, to ensure your keys are sorted you would replace `obj:` with `sorted(obj):`. Second You have currentPosition = key[str(i)], which I don't believe makes any sense as if key is a key in the dictionary then `key[str(i)]` will raise an exception as `key` is a string, and thus only valid to be indexed by an integer.

I believe a better version of the above code would be the following (note if any of my assumptions are incorrect, then let me know in a comment and I can further help you out):

obj = Mode

```
l.objects.get(Name=Request['Name'])
flag = False
for key in obj:
    currentPosition = obj[key]
    if currentPosition == request['Position']:
        flag = True
    elif flag:
        sendData.append({'Position' : currentPosition})
```

Comment: i think OP means preceding in term of alphabetic order

Comment: Yeah, I just realised I missed the point of the question a little, I'll be modifying or deleting this answer shortly.